# How to fix errors for macro that converts text to columns but only does so for even rows of A (A2, A4, etc.)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that formats a string of text in column A (string is in A2, A4, A6, etc- only even numbered rows of A) into 4 separate columns using a period as a delimiter. A QR code is scanned into cell A2, A4, A6, etc. and the information is formatted into separate columns, but when I click the button that the macro is assigned to, I get this message that populates. [image]

The message itself is not an issue but once "OK" is chosen, it repeats the message for all even numbered rows of A. The macro works just fine but after it is all finished I receive this error message.

[image]

Is there a way to remedy the multiple message boxes as well as the error? I was also wondering if there was a to edit the macro so that when a QR code is scanned into cell A2, it will automatically jump to cell A4, QR code is scanned, and it jumps to A6, etc?

```
Sub formateven()
Dim row_num As Integer
For i = 2 To 100 Step 2
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A" & i), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to say when you don't show us the code for the macro

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad so sorry! not sure how i forgot that. just added it in :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub formateven()
Dim row_num As Long
For i = 2 To 100 Step 2
    Range("B" & i & ":E" & i).clear
    Range("A" & i).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B" & i), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: i'm still getting the issue of having to click "OK" for the "there's already data there" message and i'm still getting the error after it is finished

Comment: thank you! unfortunately i still get the 400 error that i mentioned. any idea why?

Comment: Is there content in any of the target columns?

Comment: yes. the barcode is scanned into cell A2 and then gets converted from a text string to columns from A2:D2

Comment: Try putting it in B2:E2 instead

Comment: still not working, appreciate all of your help though!